# Javascript placeholders

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919086/javascript-placeholders)

Erm.. i really new to javascript and struggling big with it. The code i have is below. It's easier to explain with more code. So basically want to show each image in each placeholder but in the order i click them in. So if i click img 3 this will go to placeholder 1 then the next one i click will go to placeholder 2 if that makes sense. (this tricky bit is once one option has been chosen i want to not allow that option again. either with an error message saying already used or disappear from list)

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function showPic (whichpic) { 
    if (document.getElementById) { 
        document.getElementById('placeholder1').src = whichpic.href;
        document.getElementById('placeholder2').src = whichpic.href;
        document.getElementById('placeholder3').src = whichpic.href;
        if (whichpic.title) { 
            document.getElementById('desc').childNodes[0].nodeValue = whichpic.title; 
        } else { 
            document.getElementById('desc').childNodes[0].nodeValue = whichpic.childNodes[0].nodeValue; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } else { 
        return true; 
    } 
}
</script>

<div style="border: 1px solid #999; padding: 1em; margin: 0 0 15px 0;">
<ul>
<li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="images/img1.jpg" title="img 1">img 1</a></li>
<li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="images/img2.jpg" title="img 2">img 2</a></li>
<li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="images/img3.jpg" title="img 3">img 3</a></li>
</ul>

<p id="desc">Choose an image to begin</p>
<img id="placeholder1" src="images/blank.gif" alt="" />
<img id="placeholder2" src="images/blank.gif" alt="" />
<img id="placeholder3" src="images/blank.gif" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like there was a mistake and this was meant to be an edit, I added the content from this post to your other one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919086/javascript-placeholders Feel free to delete this question.

Comment: sorry i tried replying to someone elses question on a previous question i asked but it would not let me add enough characters so copied and pasted to ask again.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `<li>` like this. After:

```
if (whichpic.title) { 
            document.getElementById('desc').childNodes[0].nodeValue = whichpic.title; 
} else { 
            document.getElementById('desc').childNodes[0].nodeValue = whichpic.childNodes[0].nodeValue; 
}
```

And before:

```
return false;
```

Add:

```
var node = whichpic;
while(node.nodeName != 'LI' && (node = node.parentNode));
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. i just tried this but everytime i click on the href it sends me straight the the image file instead of adding it to the placeholder.

Comment: @Lee As long as it reaches the `return false` it won't do that. I had an error before  where `node = node.parentNode` was not wrapped in brackets so it may have failed there and never reached the `return false` Have you tried it with the `(node = node.parentNode)`?